# Usando regex para converter coordenadas de latitude e longitude de graus/minutos/direcao para decimal em python

Tags: python, regex, pandas, gps

Estou tentando converter dados de latitude e longitude no python que estao no seguinte formato:

```
Latitude    Longitude   
27º59' N    86º55'E
```

Estes dados foram extraidos da seguinte pagina web e convertido em um arquivo csv: http://www.peaklist.org/WWlists/WorldTop50.html

Fiz o codigo para converter mas obtive o resultado como NaN. Tentei varias formas diferentes e o ultimo codigo que tentei foi o seguinte:

```
data['Longitude'] = data['Longitude'].str.extract('°\'([N|S|E|W])', expand=True)
(parts[0].astype(int) + parts[1].astype(float) / 60) * parts[2].map({'N':1, 'S':-1, 'E': 1, 'W':-1})
```

Os dados nas colunas latitude e longitude estao no formato string.
Obrigada

Comment: Tenta este regex `r"(\d{1,2})[º](\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2})*[']\s(\w)"` funciona para `"37º45.3' E"` por exemplo. Porém se vc não tiver o `.3` (no exemplo), terá que modificar o regex um pouco.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usando isto como base: https://www.pgc.umn.edu/apps/convert

E tendo:

```
   Latitude Longitude
0  27º59' N   86º55'E
```

Acho que podes começar por criar uma função para converção de DDM para DD, nota que como não tens segundos então é assumido 0 nesse lugar:

```
import re

def convert(s):
    degrees, minutes, direction = re.split('[º\' "]+', s)
    dd = float(degrees) + float(minutes)/60
    return dd*-1 if direction in 'SW' else dd
... 
data['Latitude_dd'] = data['Latitude'].apply(convert)
data['Longitude_dd'] = data['Longitude'].apply(convert)
```

Ficamos com:

```
   Latitude Longitude  Latitude_dd  Longitude_dd
0  27º59' N   86º55'E    27.983333     86.916667
```

Penso que bate certo pois o teu exemplo sendo o monte Evereste (http://www.peaklist.org/WWlists/WorldTop50.html) o resultado deu [precisamente lá](https://www.google.com/maps/@27.983333,86.916667,59804m/data=!3m1!1e3?hl=en):

Comment: obrigada pela resposta. Infelizmente nao funcionou no meu codigo com o dataframe completo, tive como resposta: ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3). Estranho que fazendo so das linhas 1 a 10 do dataset deu certo... Os dados nas colunas estao no mesmo formato, da linha 1 a 50 entao nao entendi porque somente funcionou nas 10 primeiras linhas

Comment: Vou ver Mariana, em que linha mesmo deu o erro? Usa isto http://www.peaklist.org/WWlists/WorldTop50.html

Comment: Rodei agora a conversao para latitude e longitude em linhas separadas e a Longitude converteu as 50 linhas corretamente, mas deu erro na latitude. Os dados originais parecem ter uns espacos nas latitudes entao pode ser isso, estou vendo aqui (sou iniciante nisto mas o codigo que voce enviou ja ajudou bastante!)

Comment: Mas na minha resposta eu cobro esse cenário Mariana, copia exatamente a função que coloquei pf

Comment: @Mariana, copia e executa isto na integra: https://pastebin.com/raw/3BeYwU8u